# ie-css3.htc (Support for Css3) Not working [if someone uses it could suggest something please]

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I'm basing my project design entirely on css3 and I would like it to look good in internet explorer 8. I found this sollution http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/ . I can see that it works, but when I implement it in my website it doesn't work.

Here is what I did - I have a /css/ folder where I added ie-css3.htc file. Than in stylesheet I have the following:

```
.s {
    width: 235px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    background: #231914;

    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    float: left;

    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    -moz-transition: .2s;
    -o-transition: .2s;
    -ms-transition: .2s;
    transition: .2s;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, 0 1px 3px #54463f inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, 0 1px 3px #54463f inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, 0 1px 3px #54463f inset;

    behavior: url("ie-css3.htc"); /* This should allow rounded corners and box-shadow             
                                     in ie8 */
}
```

Can anyone suggest why it is not working?
Here is my website: http://freshbeer.lv/new/latvian/index.php
Look at the search box, it has all those css3 features

Comment: did you manage to get this working?  I'm having the problem with my IE8

Comment: @php-b-grader Yea, but i found something better, google css3 pie it has same principle, but more feature ;)

Comment: Great - I found the same solution and it worked fine as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on a behaviour for rounded corners. They're much more complex than anything a behaviour can solve.

There are also a lot of issues with IE's implementation of shadows. It requires a filter which creates a lot of ugly side-effects like disabling cleartype (font smoothing). I've done it before and the results just aren't worth it.

You might be able to get **some** of what you need using the alternative library [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) however once again I caution you that it comes with side-effects (like page lag).

At the end of the day NO version of IE prior to (and probably including) version 10 supports CSS3 adequately and no amount of javascript is going to change that. It sucks but that's the best Microsoft are prepared to offer.

The only way you'll get close to what you need is with nasty hacks and workarounds. You'll generally find they aren't worth the time and effort. Your clients can insist all they like but truth be told it's like insisting you make their Hyundai outperform a Ferrari. It's just not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You might be over this now, but according to the ie-css page, the `behavior` statement is relative to the document root. If you have it in your css dir, change the path to `/css/ie-css3.htc` so it can find the file.